# Android windowSoftInputMode issue

Tags: android, android-manifest

In my application, I am using `<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">` for the keyboard pop up effect. When used `"adjsutResize"` I see there is a little flash of black screen before the Keyboard window pops up. I do not want to see any flash in the keyboard appearance. So I tried `"stateVisible|adjustPan"` in place of `"adjsutResize"` and I got rid of flash but now for each and everytime I navigate to a page the keyboard automatically pops up (even though there is no need of its pop up) and goes hidden.
Could anyone here let me know what kind of value/param for `android:windowSoftInputMode` will help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it myself. Changing the value `android:windowSoftInputMode` to `"adjustPan"` gives the keyboard pop up the better view (transparent while popping up/down). I see no flash of the black screen before the keyboard pop up.